# Diferença entre Transaction.Commit e Transaction.CommitRetaining

Tags: delphi, transações, firedac

Usando a tecnologia FireDAC, quero saber exatamente a diferença entre `Commit` e `CommitRetaining`.

Li na documentação oficial do [FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/FireDAC.Comp.Client.TFDCustomTransaction.CommitRetaining) que o CommitRetaining mantém a transação aberta. Mas isso me gerou algumas dúvidas:

1. Qual o impacto para a aplicação de manter a transação aberta?
2. Quando eu dou um CommitRetaining pelos testes que fiz, os dados já
   ficam disponíveis para outros usuários (em outras transações)... E
   isso não consegui compreender, como é possível usuários de outras
   transações verem o que estou manipulando em uma transação ainda
   aberta?
3. A fim de evitar *DeadLocks* no sistema, qual é recomendado
   **Commit** ou **CommitRetaining**?

Alguém poderia me ajudar de forma didática a entender qual é melhor e suas diferenças?
***Detalhe***: Sistema multibanco, *FireBird* e *Oracle*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Focando no FireBird, tudo isso diz respeito ao "Isolamento Transacional"

O conceito você conhece:  Abro uma transação, enquanto eu não fizer `commit` nessa transação, outra transação não enxerga essa alteração nem pode mexer no mesmo registro.

`DeadLocks` é diferente de `Lock Conflit`. O que acontece em transações é Lock Conflit. Lock Conflit é naturalmente uma proteção aos dados, *Uma transação está mexendo nesse registro, outra transação não pode mexer ao mesmo tempo*.

Em DELPHI eles criaram um coisa que o povo do "FDD" (*Firebird Developers Day, que tive o prazer de participar em 2017*) acha "esdrúxulo". Que é o `commitretaining`. Ele COMMITA a transação mas ainda deixa ela aberta.
Esse conceito não existe EFETIVAMENTE no Banco de Dados. Commit para o Firebird "SIGNIFICA" gravar e "FECHAR".

No FDD explicaram que usar isso é muito ruim porque as transações com commitretainig continuam abertas e o Banco de Dados precisa ficar ainda controlando elas, o que 
faz oficialmente perder performance no Banco de Dados.

Recomendação de SEMPRE: Quanto mais curtas transações (abre, insere/altera/deleta, commit ou rollback) MELHOR.

[Firebird Developers Day](http://www.firebirddevelopersday.com.br/fdd/2017/index.html)

Comment: Ótimo Júnior, me ajudou a decidir que rumo seguir. Obrigado pela explanação.